# Search Vector of Strings in Clojure

Tags: string, vector, clojure

I have this vector of strings:

```
 ["a1" "b3" "q9" "c4" "l2" "b3"]
```

And if given a letter, I'd like to return the corresponding number.

So, If I'm searching for the letter q, I'd like to return 9.  If I'm searching for the letter c, I'd like to return 4.

Also I don't have to use a vector to store the strings; I just thought it was the data structure that would make the most sense.

I thought about using zipmap to create a map that I can search, but I'm not sure how to pull the strings apart.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty inefficient, Hash maps provide faster access (log32N hops) vs (logN hops) for sorted maps.  See http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-map and http://clojure.org/data_structures

Edited for completion sake:

```
(def v ["a1" "b3" "q9" "c4" "l2" "b3"])

(def my-map (apply hash-map (mapcat #(vector (subs % 0 1) (subs % 1)) v)))

(my-map "a")

=> 1
```

Comment: But how are you separating the strings? "a1", "b3" and so on...It looks like there needs to be a function before your function in order to get this one to work.

Comment: Notice that these numbers are really being saved as strings.

Comment: Edited again to show a shorter version thanks to @diego suggestion regarding `mapcat`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
(apply hash-map (mapcat seq ["a1" "b3" "q9" "c4" "l2" "b3"]))
=> {\a \1, \b \3, \c \4, \l \2, \q \9}
```

Instead of `seq` you can use a function that converts your strings into pairs of things of the types you want, if you'd rather have something other than characters.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the vector into a map is indeed a good idea. You can use [subs](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/subs/) to pull the strings apart. `(subs s 0 1)` returns the first character of the string `s` as a string and `(subs s 1)` returns the rest.

```
(def a-list ["a1" "b3" "q9" "c4" "l2" "b3"])
(def a-map
     (into {} (map (fn [s] [(subs s 0 1) (Integer/valueOf (subs s 1))])
                   a-list)))
;; => {"a" 1, "b" 3, "q" 9, "c" 4, "l" 2}
(get a-map "q")
;; => 9
```

Comment: *`(subs s 0 1)` returns the first character of the string*. Not quite. It returns a *string*, not a character. `(first s)` returns the first character.

Comment: That's why I wrote *the first character of the string s as a string*. Please edit for clarification.

Comment: Just what I was looking to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Question: What is the a-map function doing with the letter "q"? Does it become the s in the function?

Comment: @user3245240: a-map is a map value returned by the `(into {} ...)`. `(a-map "q")` is the same as `(get a-map "q")` - it returns the value for key `"q"` in the map `a-map`.

Comment: Ah. I somehow overlooked the word "get".  *Starts drinking coffee asap*

Comment: I just added it there for clarity :). If the answer was helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the letter character from the digit character by destructuring the string as an argument to a function that reduces the values into a map.  Then the character searched on is used

```
(defn search-character-vector [v ch]
  ((reduce (fn [m [c n]] (assoc m c n)) {} v) ch)
)
(search-character-vector ["a1" "b3" "q9" "c4" "l2" "b3"] \q)
```

This returns the character \9 that was linked to character \q

Answer (score 0):

You can use zipmap and re-find.

```
(def strings 
  ["a1" "b3" "q9" "c4" "l2" "b3"])

(defn from-letter [l coll]
  (let [m (zipmap
           (map #(re-find #"[a-zA-Z]{1}" %) coll)
           (map #(re-find #"\d+" %) coll))]
    (try
      (Integer/parseInt (get m l))
      (catch Exception ex nil))))

user> (from-letter "a" strings)
1
user> (from-letter "b" strings)
3
user> (from-letter "c" strings)
4
```